# Change in MUI rating component affects TextField component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, textfield, rating

I have a Material UI(MUI) `TextField` component

```
<TextField
    error={contents.desc.length > 50}
    required
    value={contents.desc}
    name="desc"
    sx={{ marginBottom: 3 }}
    label="Describe Me"
    fullWidth
    onInput={handleChange}
/>
```

and a Material UI(MUI) `Rating` component

```
<Rating
    name="rating"
    defaultValue={contents.rating}
    precision={0.5}
    sx={{ scale: "1.2" }}
    onChange={(_, value) => {
        setContents({ rating: value });
    }}
/>
```

Now, every time I change my rating, the `error` property in `TextField` throws an error like `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')`. But, that error property alone doesn't generate any error. It works perfectly once the condition is satisfied. I don't know how change in rating is affecting the `length` property of another component.
`contents` in `contents.desc` is an object with `desc` as one of its property.

Comment: `setContents({ rating: value });` _replaces_ the current state with a new object with just a `rating` property; `contents.desc` therefore no longer exists. And that's why you're getting the error.

Comment: thank you man! I totally forgot how that worked.